# How can I manipulate an array declared as `self.tab[('_',0)]` without explicitly knowing what it contains?

Tags: python, arrays

I am writing a code in python that will be reading each character from a file and save its number of occurrences. As it is a homework assignement, I am not allowed to change the way the array was declared.

The array was declared in this way:

```
    def __init__(self):
       self.tab = [('_', 0)] * 100
       self.size = 0
```

Now, every time I read a character, I check wheter I already had noticed it or not:

```
    def add(self, c): # c is the character that was read

    for i in range(0,self.size):
        if self.tab[i] == (c, ): # this is where my problem occurs. 
                                  #How should should I check if the 
                                  #character given as an argument is
                                  #present in the array I declared 
                                  #before?

            self.tab[i] = ?       #Here I want to add 1 to the number 
                                  #of occurrences of the character. 
                                  #How should I do it?
        else:
            pass
```

As I said in the question, I don't know what the character equals to and what is the number does the second column equals to. I want to be able to add 1 to the number of occurrences without knowing how many occurrences there was.

I don't expect an answer that will give me the exact solution to my particular situation. All I need is a set of rules and exemples on how to work in such cases.

Comment: Please post a correct code. What is x, what is ch in add()?

Comment: First of all, using tuple to hold values which will be often changed is bad idea, but it's not my bussines. 2. You are iterating over your tab so to check if char occurs just acces first element like this `self.tab[x][0] == ch`

Comment: @Take_Care Great, this answers one of my questions. And so, in order to change the value of occurrences, all I have to do is to write `self.tab[x][1] +=1`?

Comment: @Edward sad , but no , because You got tuple as I said. Tuple cannot be changed so everytime You must create new tuple and assing it at this postion

Comment: like this `self.tab[x] = (self.tab[x][0], self.tab[x][1]+1)`

Comment: @Edward No, that won't work because tuples are immutable (which is why it's a bad idea to use tuples for this). Frankly, that's a _really_ bad data structure for this task. As well as the tuple problem, it's not efficient to do a linear scan over a list to look for matching characters unless the list s _really_ small. It _is_ possible to search an ordered list more efficiently, using bisection, but that adds unnecessary complexity. The sensible way to do this in Python would be to use the Counter class defined in the `collections` module. To do it "manually" you should use a dictionary.

Comment: Had you thought about a new instructor who chooses examples that will actually help you develop your ability to _use_ Python rather than wallow in its trivialities?

Comment: @holdenweb I wish that was an option for me, unfortunately it isn't.

Comment: In which case you have my sympathy. The obstacles in your path are the immmutability of tuples (meaning you have to create new tuples to update a count) and locating a character. You might also want to ask what happens with an input file containing all 128 ASCII characters ... or even any message with more than 100 unique characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, this is *not* a great data structure to use for this problem.

Firstly, tuples are immutable, i.e., they can't be updated. To change a string or integer in one of those `self.tab` tuples you basically need to create a new tuple and replace the original one. So there's really not much point in initialising the list with 100 tuples that are going to be discarded. Secondly, it's not efficient to do a linear scan over a list to look for matching characters.

The sensible way to do this task in Python would be to use the Counter class defined in the collections module. However, it's also quite easy to implement this using a plain dictionary, or a defaultdict.

But anyway, here's one way to do it using the data structure given in the question.

```
class CharCounter(object):
    def __init__(self):
       self.tab = [('_', 0)] * 100
       self.size = 0 

    def add(self, c): # c is the character that was read
        for i in range(1 + self.size):
            ch, count = self.tab[i]
            if ch == c:
                self.tab[i] = (c, count + 1)
                break
        else:
            self.tab[self.size] = (c, 1)
            self.size += 1

# test
counter = CharCounter()
for c in 'this is a test':
    counter.add(c)

for i in range(counter.size):
    print(i, counter.tab[i])
```

**output**

```
0 ('t', 3)
1 ('h', 1)
2 ('i', 2)
3 ('s', 3)
4 (' ', 3)
5 ('a', 1)
6 ('e', 1)
```

Note that this code does *not* add any `_` chars found in the input. Presumably, `_` is being used to indicate an empty table slot; it would be more usual in Python to use an empty string, `None`, or perhaps a sentinel object (eg an instance of `object`).

Comment: If I understood correctly, the way to do it with tuples is very inefficient, although it does work. I am right?

Comment: @Edward: Indeed! There might be worse ways to do this in Python, but I'm having a hard time thinking of them. :)

Comment: This is very reassuring concerning my instructor! Anyway, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

To check if your character is already present in the tab, you can use something like:

```
found_char = [arr_item for arr_item in self.tab if arr_item[0]==c]
```

and check the returned value:

```
if found_char == []:
    # add a new entry in your tab using the self.size attribute.
else:
    # use self.tab.index(...) to find the corresponding tupple in self.tab and 
    # replace it by a modified one as tupple are immutable.
```

Comment: This approach is even more inefficient: the `.index` method has to do another linear scan (albeit at C speed) to find the tuple's index in the table.